# How to change the font size of a JLabel that is in a "panel.add(new JLabel(""));"

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I know how to change the font size of a JLabel the normal way

```
exampleLabel.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 20));
```

But im looking to see if there is a way of doing it when you add a JLabel to a panel the simple way. like this..

```
examplePanel.add(new JLabel("this is an example"));
```

How would i change the font size of the latter, seeing as the JLabel doesn't have a name?

i tried setting the font on the JPanel but it doesn't work.

```
examplePanel.setFont(.......);
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: `I know how to change the font size of a JLabel the normal way` - then use the normal way. Its normal for a reason. There is no reason to use the other approach. The solution you have will only work if all the labels are on the same panel. Rarely will you create a GUI with a single panel and single layout manager. Keep the solution simple.

Comment: I resorted to using the normal way, i was just seeing if there was a simpler way in doing it. I'm new to GUI's, only started fairly recently. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a strange way to access a `JLabel` but this may work ...

```
Component[] components = examplePanel.getComponents();

for (Component singleComponent : components) {
   if (singleComponent instanceof JLabel) {
       JLabel label = (JLabel) singleComponent;

       if ("this is an example".equals(label.getText()) {
              label.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 20));
       }
   }
}
```

Another way, create a new class for those `JLabels` that you want to change.

```
public class JMyFontLabel extends JLabel {
  boolean applyFontChange = false;

  public JMyFontLabel(String text, boolean applyFontChange) {
         super(text);
         this.applyFontChange = applyFontChange;
  }

  // get / set methods for applyFontChange.
} 

// Method to apply font
public void setMyFont(JPanel examplePanel, Font myFont) {
   Component[] components = examplePanel.getComponents();

   for (Component singleComponent : components) {

   if (singleComponent instanceof JMyFontLabel) {
       JMyFontLabel label = (JMyFontLabel) singleComponent;

       if (label.isApplyFontChange()) {
          label.setFont(myFont);
       }
   }
}
```

On label creation, set `applyFontChange`

```
   examplePanel.add(new JMyFontLabel("Name", true));
```

Comment: The thing is, i have multiple labels that ill be using in a GridLayout, for example i have a label with the text "Name :" then the label next to it will be 'new JLabe(student.getName())' ... So i dont wanna have to write a for loop for every single JLabel.

Comment: You can write a method or create a new class for those labels that you want to change. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Aaronward Updated answer.